# How to make has_many :through association with fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, fixtures

I can't use `factory_girl` because I'm testing sunspot and need real database.

**Edit**: nope. It can works with sunspot. I'm wrong.

How can I build has_many :through(a.k.a many-to-many) associations in fixtures?

I google it and get a [invalid solution](http://osdir.com/ml/RubyonRailsTalk/2010-06/msg00199.html)

**Edit**:

Finally I use factory_girl. I google-copy-paste a snippet:

```
factory :tagging do 
    question { |a| a.association(:question) } 
    tag { |a| a.association(:tag) } 
end
```

(question has_many tags through taggings, vice versa)

It works well. But what's it? The factory_girl's readme didn't meantion this syntax.
Could someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the official documentation for factory_girl, which is very complete, [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

[Here](http://dtuite.github.com/factory-girl-2.html) is a nice (shorter) blogpost explaining factory_girl 2 (comparing it with factory-girl 1).

UPDATED:

To Explain the code a bit:

```
 factory :tagging do
   association :tag
 end
```

will look for a factory called `:tag` and will construct that object, and then link that to the association `tag` (e.g. a `belongs_to`) that is there inside your object `:tagging`.

Please note: this is the default factory. If you want `taggings` to share a `tag`, you will need to do something like

```
@tag = Factory(:tag)
@tagging_1 = Factory(:tagging, :tag => @tag)
@tagging_2 = Factory(:tagging, :tag => @tag)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does `association` return? Neither the two document says.

Comment: Your solution isn't equivalent to mine. The `association :tag` will call FactoryGirl.create(:tag) or something. So if two taggings belong to the same tag, it will be create twice. My (googled) solution avoids this.

Comment: Imho solution is identical. But indeed the associated `tag` will be created twice. If you hand an explicit `:tag` parameter to the factory, it will use that instead. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a classic has_and_belongs_to_many association, without other information in the association model, I think the conventions allow you to write your fixtures like that :

```
#users.yml
john:
  first_name: John
  last_name: Doe
  hobbies: [swim, play_tennis]

#hobbies.yml
swim:
  name: Swim

play_tennis:
  name: Play Tennis
```

But I'm not completely sure !

Answer (score 0):

I used fixtures on testing for `has_many :through` by hash `merge`

```
# posts.yml
one:
  title: "Railscasts"
  url: "http://railscasts.com/"
  description: "Ruby on Rails screencasts"

# categories.yml
one:
  name: "magazine"
two:
  name: "tutorial"
three:
  name: "news"
four:
  name: "Ruby"

# posts_controller_test.rb
def test_post_create
  assert_difference 'Post.count' do
    post :create, post: posts(:one).attributes
     .merge(categories: [categories(:two), categories(:four)])
  end
end
```

when after adding another fixture file, and tried this it didn't work

```
# post_categories.yml
one:
  post: one
  category: two
two:
  post: one
  category: four

def test_post_create
  assert_difference 'Post.count' do
    post :create, post: posts(:one)
  end
end

puts posts(:one).attributes
# {"id"=>980190962, "url"=>"http://railscasts.com/", "title"=>"Railscasts", "description"=>"Ruby on Rails screencasts", "created_at"=>Thu, 14 May 2015 18:27:20 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 14 May 2015 18:27:20 UTC +00:00}

puts posts(:one).attributes
      .merge(categories: [categories(:two), categories(:four)])
# {"id"=>980190962, "url"=>"http://railscasts.com/", "title"=>"Railscasts", "description"=>"Ruby on Rails screencasts", "created_at"=>Thu, 14 May 2015 18:30:23 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 14 May 2015 18:30:23 UTC +00:00, "category_ids"=>[980190962, 1018350795]}
```